# redireccionar a un div en especifico con php en laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, laravel

me ha surgido una duda del como podria despues de registrar unos campos de un formlario hacer que regrese a un div en especifico, me explico, lo que pasa es que estoy manejando distintos formularios en html y estoy ocupando algunos eventos en Js para que al momento de presionar un boton me mande al formulario requerido y se oculten los demas, cuando estoy en ese formulario en especifico mando los datos a php para que los inserte en una db pero quiero que cuando se ingresen me quede en el mismo formulario en el que estoy trabajando ya que lo que me esta pasando se refresca la pagina y me manda la la principal donde estan todos los otros formularios y asi no se puede ver si ocurrio algun error ejemplo si el usuario no completo un campo o ingreso algo mal
este es mi codigo en html

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('upload.file')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="address_information" id="producto">
        <div class="options_save">
                <div class="title_address">
                    <h3>Registro de Productos</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="icon_save">
                    <input type="image" src="{!! asset('img/editar.png') !!}" height="30" width="30" class="btn-option">
                </div>
                <div class="icon_save">
                    <button type="reset" value="limpiar" class="btn btn-light btn-option"><img src="{!! asset('img/escoba.png')!!}"  height="20" width="20" /></button>
                </div>

                <div class="icon_save">
                    <button type="button"  id="promo" class="btn btn-light btn-option"><img src="{!! asset('img/promotion.png')!!}"  height="20" width="20" /></button>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Marca</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="redondeado">
            <div id="mostrar_marca"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group linea" id="date">
            <label>Nombre del producto</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="producto" id="marca" class="redondeado">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Precio compra</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="compra" id="marca" class="redondeado">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Precio Venta</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="venta" id="marca" class="redondeado">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Categoria del producto</label>
           <select class="redondeado" name="tipo">
               @foreach($product as $r)
               <option value="{{$r->Id_Tipo_Producto}}">{{$r->Nombre_Tipo}}</option>
               @endforeach
           </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Descripcion:</label>
            <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="1" cols="10">

            </textarea>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Manual</label><br>
            <input type="file" name="manual" title="Seleccione un documento">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="{{route('register.promotion')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="address_information" id="promocion">
        <div class="options_save">
                <div class="title_address">
                    <h3>Promociones de productos</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="icon_save">
                    <input type="image" src="{!! asset('img/editar.png') !!}" height="30" width="30" class="btn-option">
                </div>

                <div class="icon_save" id="limpiar">
                    <button type="reset" value="limpiar" class="btn btn-light btn-option"><img src="{!! asset('img/escoba.png')!!}"  height="20" width="20" /></button>
                </div>

                <div class="icon_save">
                    <button type="button" id="regresar" class="btn btn-light btn-option"><img src="{!! asset('img/regreso.png')!!}"  height="20" width="20" /></button>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Seleccionar Producto</label><br>
            <select class="redondeado" name="producto">
                @foreach($product_list as $r)
                <option value="{{$r->Id_Producto}}">{{$r->Nombre}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Fecha Inicial</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="inicial" id="from" class="redondeado"><br>
            {!! $errors->first('inicial','<small class="warning_message">:message</small><br>') !!}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Fecha Final</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="final" id="to" class="redondeado">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Descuento Aplicado</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="descuento" id="descuento" class="redondeado">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Descripcion:</label>
            <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="1" cols="10">

            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Precio</label><br>
            @foreach($product_list as $r)
            <label><h5>{{$r->Precio_Venta}}</h5></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$r->Precio_Venta}}" id="precio_venta">
            @endforeach
        </div>

        <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Precio con Descuento</label><br>

            <label id="precio_final"></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="precio_final" id="precio_final_hidden">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

al momento que el usuario hace click en el boton con el id promo lo manda al div formulario de abajo que es el que tiene el id promocion 
al ingresar los campos ahi claro se refresca la pagina y me aparece solo el principal que es el de producto
este es mi codigo en js donde oculto los formularios

```
 $('#promo').click(function(){
        document.getElementById('producto').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('promocion').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('servicio').style.display='none';
        $('#identificador').val(10);
        $('#precio_final').text(0.00);
    });
```

el metodo que esta trabajando para la inserccion del segundo formulario es este

```
 public function registerPromotionProducto(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'inicial'=>'required',
        'final'=>'required',
        'descuento'=>'required'
    ]);
    $result=DB::statement('call registro_promo_producto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[
        $request->input('producto'),
        $request->input('inicial'),
        $request->input('final'),
        $request->input('descuento'),
        $request->input('precio_final'),
        $request->input('descripcion'),
        "insertar"
    ]);


}
```

espero y alguien me pueda ayudar muchas gracias

Comment: Está interesante, no tengo ni idea, pero me gustaría ver cómo. Aunque, la verdad, no entiendo como para qué ¿por qué no son vistas independientes y te evitas ese problema? ¿Cuál es el problema de fondo a resolver?

Comment: Hola luisfer lo estoy trabajando de ese modo no se si estoy bien pero es casi inmediata la cara ya que esta uno en la misma pagina, si hago lo mismo en una seccion diferente hay unos milisegundos que tarda en cargar

Comment: Lo más sencillo ahí parece ser usando ajax para enviar el formulario, pues así no se va a recargar la página. Para lo que preguntas del redirect, puedes probar con un `return redirect('/tu-uri#promocion');` en el método del controlador.

Comment: gracias lo voy a probar, he usado ajax para un completador puede que si funcione de ese modo, un saludo

Comment: O quizás esto sea una tarea más bien para algo tipo Vue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de poder hacer eso, una seria regresando una variable de session de 1 solo uso o Flashed Session Data

Al final de tu funcion "registerPromotionProducto" agrega:

```
return redirect()->back()->with("retorno", true);
```

y en tu vista con javascript puedes hacer una validacion si esa variable existe y asi hacer el scroll a el div

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      @if(session()->has('retorno'))
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#id-div").offset().top
         }, 2000);
      @endif
    });
</script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no tenia idea como redireciconar a un div en especifico